# Solve Unable to Solve with Inexact Coefficients

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

I am trying to find fixed points for a set of 3 differential equations by setting the first derivatives to zero. I plug these equations into Mathematica's Solve[] function like this:

```
Solve[((0) == (0.01*H*(1 - Exp[-P*0.00001]) - 0.0001*H)) && 
      ((0) == (0.01*P*(1 - Exp[-TR*0.00001]) - 0.001*P - H*(1 - Exp[-P*0.00001]))) && 
      ((0) == (0.01*TR*(-TR*0.0002)) - 0.1*P*(1 - Exp[-TR*0.00001])) && 
      (H > 0) && (P > 0) && (TR > 0), 
      {H, P, TR}]
```

I get the warning, "Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result."
No result is shown, however.

I would appreciate it if someone could explain both this warning, and the lack of output. Thank you.

Comment: I get `{}` as output. The result `{}` indicates that there are no solutions.  (See the fourth bullet under "Details and Options" in the documentation for `Solve`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning occurs because you used inexact numbers like `0.01` rather than `1/100`. The symbolic methods `Solve` uses are intolerant of approximate arithmetic. So, it replaced them all with exact numbers. It yielded an empty solution set because it couldn't find a solution to the exact equations.